# Different output while creating threads with OpenMP in C++ and calling Fortran code from the threads

Tags: c++, fortran, openmp

I am working on a problem where the C++ code calls a Fortran subroutine (.f). The C++ creates an array (A_in), passes it to Fortran and receives various other arrays (B_out, C_out, D_out)

I would like to check the output for various different A_in, thus I created threads with OpenMP and call the Fortran subroutine from each thread. But every time I run the complete code, it produces different outputs.

The code snippet is as follow:

```
C++ code:

#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {void int_fort_(double *B_out, double *C_out, double *D_out, double *A_in);}

int main() {

double *B_full = (double *) new double[70];
double *C_full = (double *) new double[70];
double *D_full = (double *) new double[70];

omp_set_num_threads(10);

#pragma omp parallel
{
int id = omp_get_thread_num();

double *A_in = (double *) new double[7];

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) A_in[i] = id;

double *B_out = (double *) new double[7];
double *C_out = (double *) new double[7];
double *D_out = (double *) new double[7];

*initializing B_out, C_out, D_out*

int_fort_(B_out, C_out, D_out, A_in);

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) B_full[i+(7*id)] = B_out[i];
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) C_full[i+(7*id)] = C_out[i];
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) D_full[i+(7*id)] = D_out[i];
}

cout << "B_full" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 70; i++) cout << B_full[i] << " ";
cout << endl;

cout << "C_full" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 70; i++) cout << C_full[i] << " ";
cout << endl;

cout << "D_full" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 70; i++) cout << D_full[i] << " ";
cout << endl;


return 0;
}



Fortran code:
I am treating subroutine int_fort(B,C,D,A) as a blackbox because it is a very big and complex code.

Compile Command:
ifort -m64 -02 -o int_fort.o -c int_fort.f
g++ -fopenmp -Wall -02 -fno-exception -fno-rtti -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -fopenmp -Wall -02 -fno-exception -fno-rtti -o run main.o int_fort.o
./run
```

In the above code, A_in, B_out, C_out, D_out are inputs to the fortran subroutine int_fort. It produces output and places it in B_out, C_out, D_out.
For various values of A_in, I place the output values of B_out, C_out, D_out in B_full, C_full and D_full respectively.

But each time I run the code, it produces different outputs for B_out, C_out, D_out and B_full, C_full, D_full and the answers do not match to the original code (without threads) for various input values of A_in.

I am new to OpenMp and Fortran and was not able to understand the problem. How can I change the program to make it produce same output as running the code in serial (instead of creating threads).

If it helps, I am working in opensuse using visual studio code.

I also tried to put the block

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) B_full[i+(7*id)] = B_out[i];
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) C_full[i+(7*id)] = C_out[i];
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) D_full[i+(7*id)] = D_out[i];
```

in #pragma omp critical to reduce false sharing but still it produces different outputs at every run.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. What kimd of Fortran code is that? Is it supposed to be thread safe? I think the Fortran code is necessary. See [mcve].

Comment: You cannot assume the thread-safety of the Fortran routine if the developer has not stated it was thread-safe, and without looking at the code. A common cause of non thread safety comes from the use of static variables (common blocks, module variables, variable declared with the `SAVE`attribute, and more misleading the variables initialised upon declaration in routines, which correspond to an implied `SAVE`).

Comment: By the way: you should compile your Fortran routine with the `-qopenmp`option, even if it doesn't contain any OpenMP directive. This tells the compiler to allocate all local variables on the stack, otherwise the compiler is free to set them static. Still, this option can do nothing for all the cases I have listed in the previous comment.

Comment: An off-topic comment: calling `omp_set_num_threads` doesn't guarantee that the OpenMP runtime will use exactly the specified number of threads. I suggest either check it or using `#pragma omp parallel for`, which work for any number of threads.

Comment: Fortran has strange rules regarding private variables in functions. Make sure non of your variables have the `SAVE` attribute, for instance by being value-initialized.

Comment: @Victor I already mentioned the general issue with static variables (and not only the `SAVE`'d ones) and multithreading... BTW these are not "strange rules", these are just rules that one has to know when using a language.

Comment: @PierU Ah yes, I see you did. But even as a long-time Fortran programmer I cannot help but finding these rules at least a little counter-intuitive.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава, Thank you very much for your response and the links. The Fortran code is proprietary, thus I won't be able to minimally reproduce it here (also given the length of the code). The "int_fort(B,C,D,A)" subroutine calls various other Fortran subroutine as well as some Lapack functions. I don't know if it is thread safe or not as no information about it was given to me. I have to believe that it is not thread safe.

Comment: @PierU Thank you very much for the detailed reply! I'll need to check thread safety for the Fortran code.

Comment: @Laci Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I have also implemented the #pragma omp parallel for.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you for your reply. I'll check the code for variables that have the SAVE attribute and try to remove them.

Comment: Put `#pragma omp critical` before calling the fortran function. if your problem is solved, the function is not threadsafe. If it is not resolved, I have no idea what is going on...

Comment: @Laci Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I tried that. The function works withing critical block.